# How to search through a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, jagged-arrays

This code should search an array of decimals for elements that are in a specified range, and return the number of occurrences of the elements that matches the range criteria.

The problem is that I am having trouble in accessing the jagged array, my code:

```cs
public static int GetDecimalsCount(decimal[] arrayToSearch, decimal[][] ranges)
{
    if (arrayToSearch is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
    }
    else if (ranges is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ranges));
    }
    else
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSearch.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ranges.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < ranges[j].Length; n++)
                {
                    if (arrayToSearch[i] >= ranges[j][n] && arrayToSearch[i] <= ranges[j][n + 1])
                    {
                        sum++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

The ranges are from lowest to highest so it will always be arrays of two decimals

I was also confident this at least should work:

```
if (arrayToSearch[i] >= ranges[j][0] && arrayToSearch[i] <= ranges[j][1])
```

How does it not compare the array, I don't understand.

**EDIT 1: Data in Arrays from Test**

Inserting some of the test code, if you need full I can send it. It's a little long and it has unimportant test cases for other assignments.

```cs
private static readonly decimal[] ArrayWithFiveElements = { 0.1m, 0.2m, 0.3m, 0.4m, 0.5m };
private static readonly decimal[] ArrayWithFifteenElements = { decimal.MaxValue, -0.1m, -0.2m, decimal.One, -0.3m, -0.4m, -0.5m, decimal.Zero, 0.1m, 0.2m, 0.3m, 0.4m, 0.5m, decimal.MinusOne, decimal.MinValue };

[Test]
public void DecimalCounter_FiveElementsOneRange_ReturnsResult()
{
    // Arrange
    decimal[][] ranges =
    {
        new[] { 0.1m, 0.2m },
    };

    // Act
    int actualResult = DecimalCounter.GetDecimalsCount(DecimalCounterTests.ArrayWithFiveElements, ranges);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(2, actualResult);
}

[Test]
public void DecimalCounter_FiveElementsTwoRanges_ReturnsResult()
{
    // Arrange
    decimal[][] ranges =
    {
        new[] { 0.1m, 0.2m },
        new[] { 0.4m, 0.5m },
    };

    // Act
    int actualResult = DecimalCounter.GetDecimalsCount(DecimalCounterTests.ArrayWithFiveElements, ranges);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(4, actualResult);
}
```

Comment: _How does it not compare the array_ : What happens? - `ranges[n][j]` did you mean `ranges[j][n]` ?

Comment: I am doing this with tests and all of them fail, was not organized by me. It's an assignment. I also tried ` ranges[j][n] ` however the result is the same. I think  ` ranges[j][n] ` is more correct then previuos, i'll change it.

Comment: What does the data in your arrays looks like

Comment: @CaiusJard EDIT 1

Comment: Also, because you access `ranges[j][n + 1]`, you must limit the inner most loop variable to `n < ranges[j].Length - 1` (with the additional `- 1`). Otherwise `[n + 1]` will attempt to access an element out of the range.

Comment: If the ranges always consist of two numbers, I would use a an array of tuples instead of a jagged array.: `(decimal start, decimal end)[] = { (0.1m, 0.2m), (0.4m, 0.5m) };` Test with `if (arrayToSearch[i] >= ranges[j].start && arrayToSearch[i] <= ranges[j].end)`

Comment: Unfortunatly using a jagged array is a requirement for this assignment.

Comment: This should work: `if (arrayToSearch[i] >= ranges[j][0] && arrayToSearch[i] <= ranges[j][1])` and of course then you don't need the inner most loop (3rd loop). Why do you think it does not work? [Debug your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) to see what happens.

Comment: Did you try the debugger, which is the tool of choice here..?

Comment: so I found whats wrong with everything here, it was unexpected, the testcases were overloaded with next assignment and it showed me that I green'd only 6 of 40 testcases. I tried to go to the next assignment and guess what, when I did that what I thought was correct suddenly after testing my first assignment was all green. So now everything is good, thank you for your time and sorry this was my first time with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the errors pointed out in the comments I don't find any problem in the code ; https://dotnetfiddle.net/F6Yjy0

```
public static int GetDecimalsCount(decimal[] arrayToSearch, decimal[][] ranges)
{
    if (arrayToSearch == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
    }
    else if (ranges == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ranges));
    }
    else
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSearch.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ranges.Length; j++)
            {
                //for (int n = 0; n < ranges[j].Length; n++)
                //{
                    if (arrayToSearch[i] >= ranges[j][0] && arrayToSearch[i] <= ranges[j][1])
                    {
                        sum++;
                    }
                //}
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

The innermost loop is rather pointless; it only runs once and can be replaced with indexing 0/1. Removing it also removes the OOB problem